Выдаёт ошибку при запросе message.forward_from_chat.id (telebot)
Он выдаёт ошибку при запросе message.forward_from_chat.id
Код ошибки:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Что мне делать?

global w

w = bot.forward_message(i, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id) # i это таблица chat админов

print(w.forward_from_chat.id)


Причина в том, что метод forward_message возвращает объект Message, если пересылка сообщения прошла успешно, или None, если произошла ошибка. В вашем случае, скорее всего, пересылка сообщения не удалась, и поэтому переменная w имеет значение None.
if w is not None:
    print(w.forward_from_chat.id)

